# Plotting a Large Data Set in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot a two vectors that have 266 elements against one another. I keep getting the error "error using tabular/ plot. Too many input arguments" How can I get around this error and plot all my data points?

```
runOneVolume = titrationData(1:249, 'runOneVolume');
runTwoVolume = titrationData(1:241, 'runTwoVolume');
runThreeVolume = titrationData(1:243, 'runThreeVolume');
runFourVolume = titrationData(:, 'runFourVolume');
runFiveVolume = titrationData(1:266, 'runFiveVolume');
runSixVolume = titrationData(1:222, 'runSixVolume');

runOnepH = titrationData(1:249, 'runOnepH');
runTwopH = titrationData(1:241, 'runTwopH');
runThreepH = titrationData(1:243, 'runThreepH');
runFourpH= titrationData(:, 'runFourpH');
runFivepH = titrationData(1:266, 'runFivepH');
runSixpH = titrationData(1:222, 'runSixpH');


plot(runOneVolume, runOnepH) %This line gave the error

>> whos
Name                   Size             Bytes  Class    Attributes

runFiveVolume        266x1               3186  table              
runFivepH            266x1               3178  table              
runFourVolume       1165x1              10378  table              
runFourpH           1165x1              10370  table              
runOneVolume         249x1               3048  table              
runOnepH             249x1               3040  table              
runSixVolume         222x1               2832  table              
runSixpH             222x1               2824  table              
runThreeVolume       243x1               3004  table              
runThreepH           243x1               2996  table              
runTwoVolume         241x1               2984  table              
runTwopH             241x1               2976  table              
titrationData       1165x12            115592  table
```

Comment: Can you show us the line that generates the error?

Comment: what version of matlab are you using and what code are you using to try to generate the plot.  Your problem likely is that you are plotting a table and not a vector.

Comment: The line that generates the error is plot(runOneVolume, runOnepH) @mrbolichi

Comment: I'm using Matlab R2018b. I started by doing this

runOneVolume = titrationData(1:249, 'runOneVolume');
runTwoVolume = titrationData(1:241, 'runTwoVolume');
runThreeVolume = titrationData(1:243, 'runThreeVolume');
runFourVolume = titrationData(:, 'runFourVolume');
runFiveVolume = titrationData(1:266, 'runFiveVolume');
runSixVolume = titrationData(1:222, 'runSixVolume');

I did the same thing for the pH data
then I tried plot(runOneVolume, runOnepH)

Comment: "I'm trying to plot a two vectors" No, you're not. They're tables. You cannot plot one table against another. Extract the relevant column from each table and plot those.

Answer (score 2):

Since these are tables, you need to extract the values:

```
runOneVolume = titrationData{1:249, 'runOneVolume'};
runOnepH = titrationData{1:249, 'runOnepH'};
plot(runOneVolume, runOnepH)
```

Alternatively, try this:

```
plot(titrationData.runOneVolume(1:249), titrationData.runOnepH(1:249))
```